# Word for dress-like garment with shorts instead of skirt?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

A dress is a one-piece garment containing a skirt. What's the word for a one-piece garment that looks like a dress, except it has shorts instead? Are there any qualifiers depending on the length of the shorts?

Comment: Actually, "skort" is a garment that starts at the waist, it's not a whole-body garment like a dress, @PhilSweet

Comment: I think any question about names of clothing articles needs to clearly specify if they want answers for BE or AmE, because the answers will most likely be different.

Comment: @T.E.D. there are many clothing terms that have different meanings in AmE and BE. Commonly known examples are *jumper*, *pinafore*, and *pants*. In AmE it's perfectly acceptable to walk out in public with your pants showing. In BE, not so much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is called a 'Playsuit'.  If the length of the shorts increases enough that they become trousers, it would become a 'Jumpsuit'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playsuit_(ladies%27_clothing)

Comment: In the US in 2017, only children wear playsuits, regardless of what the garment looks like.

Comment: @1006a: Well, children, [and Taylor Swift](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2678640/Taylor-Swift-ramps-retro-glamour-figure-hugging-floral-playsuit.html), as the Wikipedia article shows.

Comment: @1006a - Yeah, this is clearly a BE answer. "Trousers" isn't a term used often in the US (its "pants"). I believe here its called a "romper" (Kristina's answer).

Comment: @sleske That link is to a *Daily Mail* article, though, which I'm pretty sure is a British rag. La Swift herself didn't call it that.

Comment: @1006a the rag in question is indeed British, though with quite a strong online presence in the US market.

Comment: @ChrisH but that wouldn't change the words they would use imo

Comment: @AytAyt their online branch has quite a large US staff, so some American influence creeps in. But not in this case

Answer (score 43):

The one-piece garment with shorts is sometimes referred to as a **"romper"**, as shown [here](https://www.target.com/p/women-s-homecoming-romper-xhilaration-153-juniors/-/A-52722402#lnk=sametab) - from a recent online catalog in the US:

[image]

Thanks to @RaceYouAnytime's generosity, here are some additional notes regarding "romper":

> The OED describes "romper" as originally referring to a garment worn
> by children, but it can also refer to adult garments of this sort.
>
> 2.a. A one-piece garment covering the trunk and all or part of the legs, worn esp. as a playsuit by a young child; (subsequently also) an
> all-in-one outer garment for a baby.
>
> 2.b. An item of clothing of related design worn by adults: spec. (a) a fashionable, loose-fitting woman's garment combining esp. a short-sleeved or sleeveless top and wide-legged shorts

Comment: Woops, I didn't live up to my username this time, you beat me.  +1.

Comment: Awww!  I like your answer better - throw in a picture and I'll delete mine!

Comment: Note that some people recently have been trying to promote similar one-piece outfits for men as [romp*him*s](https://www.romphim.com/) .

Comment: @T.E.D. Oh god. I hope that doesn't catch on - the word or the style...

Comment: And this is very much an American English answer

Comment: @T.E.D. That is… truly abominable. Cannot unsee.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Then you (and Michael and his 8 upvoters) had definitely better not go to twitter and look at the [#romphim hashtag](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23romphim)

Comment: @T.E.D. I’ll make sure I stay well clear of that. (The word is actually worse than the item to me.)

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard that referred to as a jumper

Comment: [Really](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jumper&num=50&tbm=isch)?

Comment: Yes, really.  Unless I'm watching BBC America ;-)

Comment: I've heard 'jumper' when it ends in a skirt, and 'romper' when it ends in shorts. When I was in school we had a uniform and the girls outfits were called 'jumpers', it was a dress-like outfit worn over a t-shirt. (US English)

Answer (score 1):

In Australian English this item of dress is a *jumpsuit*.

[This fashion website lists jumpsuits for sale](http://www.bestproducts.com/fashion/g925/jumpsuits-for-women/)

The length of the legs does not change the name of the item. The defining feature is that it is a slim-fitting top and bottom in one piece.  Slim-fitting in that it is not a '[onesie'](http://mashable.com/2013/11/09/best-adult-onesies/#9dJxtbV5eqqs).  Top and bottom in that it is not a overall/coverall/dungaree that requires a separate t-shirt underneath.

I believe these items were last fashionable here in the 1970's and have had a recent resurgence in popularity.

Answer (score 0):

If the lower part is full length and it is a functional garment (rather than a fashion garment), it could be called a coverall (or coveralls). If the top of it is a bib rather than a sleeved garment, it would be called overalls or (rarely) dungarees.